# Converting EPUB to PDF with Java

Tags: java, pdf, epub

I would like to convert an EPUB document into a PDF using Java.
I found a lot of questions about converting PDF to EPUB but nothing the other way around.

Is there a Java library or a command-line tool that I could call through Java that would do the magic?

Thx in advance!

-Gesh

Comment: since epub is basically packaged html, you may want to try to split the problem into two parts:
1. Unzip using existing libraries
2. Convert html to pdf

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. What differences, except of the packaging, has epub compared to html that could cause problems in converting?

Comment: There's also a set of standard xml files that provide meta-data.  If you just want the text, you can ignore most of it.

Comment: It seems to be a little bit more complicated. Sure, if you only want the text the html-files are fine. But if you want the exact order of the html files, the right fonts and images, you have to parse the meta-data too.

Comment: Indeed you can access with Zip to the content of any file within the container, the table of content (the ncx file in epub 2) will provide the order in which each html file should be converted. Zip should also provide access to any image, css or font file included.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not afraid of using online service then [EPUB to PDF Rest API](https://www.convertapi.com/epub-to-pdf) could be used.

The actual JAVA code will look like

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        TreeMap params = new TreeMap<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);

        params.put("File", "C:\path\to\test-epub.epub");
        params.put("Secret", "<secret>");

        CloseableHttpResponse response = ConvertApi.convert("epub", "pdf", params);
        System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8"));
    }
}

class ConvertApi {
    public static CloseableHttpResponse convert(String srcFormat, String dstFormat, TreeMap params) throws IOException {
        MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        params.forEach((k, v) -> {
            if(Files.exists(Paths.get(v))) {
                builder.addBinaryBody(k, new File(v));
            } else {
                builder.addTextBody(k, v, ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
            }
        });

        String authParam = params.get("secret") == null ? String.format("Token=%s", params.get("token")) : String.format("Secret=%s", params.get("secret"));
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(String.format("https://v2.convertapi.com/%s/to/%s?%s", srcFormat, dstFormat, authParam));
        httpPost.setEntity(builder.build());
        return httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call Calibre's program called [ebook-convert](https://manual.calibre-ebook.com/generated/en/ebook-convert.html) from command line. See the [Calibre manual](https://manual.calibre-ebook.com/conversion.html) for more information.

I believe the conversion works fine for simple requirements. I tried to use it for e-book conversion (ePUB to PDF), but was not able not control some document parameters (indentation of page number etc.). The result contained all text from the source ePUB, it was usable, but I was not happy with the quality of formatting.

Finally I ended up with parsing ePUB and using PrinceXML for HTML to PDF conversion. The good thing about this is I can remove the ePUB table of contents (hyperlinks without page numbers) with a completely different ToC (hyperlinks with page numbers), I can add empty pages where appropriate etc. The PrinceXML is a binary, which you can run from command line or you can execute it via [Java wrapper](https://www.princexml.com/download/wrappers/), it works very well and has a wide support of HTML/CSS.

Karel